# How to animate a div larger, then making it smaller again?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Sup guys! I have a little problem that I need to fix, here's my website at the moment: [My Website](http://joel-telleborn.ostersjo.nu)

And my problem here is, that if you click the twitch button, 4 images of my favorite streamers slide down. Then if you scroll down, you can see that div is not large enough, I've succeeded to fix this with a jquery command. It follows like this:

```
$("#twitchbutton").click(function(){
 $("#main-content").animate({height: "1200px"});
  });
```

this works, but if you click it again, it stays at this height.. I want it to slide back to 900px.. How can I do this? Any answers are appreciated!

Comment: Wheres the twitch button?

Comment: @AndrewHoffman doesn't really matter, does it?

Comment: Nm I found it. I couldn't see what he was talking about if I can't find it. ;)

Comment: @AndrewHoffman ow, on his site! I didn't even see he posted a link to it lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about getting the height of the element. if it is 900, make it 1200, else, make it 1200..

so something like this: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bmzw80py/)

```
$("#twitchbutton").click(function(){
    if ($("#main-content").height() == 900){
        $("#main-content").animate({height: "1200px"});
    } else {
        $("#main-content").animate({height: "900px"});
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :D It helped! This is probably something really easy, but I don't know much about the "if" and "else" commands in jquery ^^ haha thanks anyway! ♥

Comment: if else in jQuery works just like if else in any other language. Anyways, click the little green check and we are all done here :p

Answer (score 1):

@Froz set height to auto and you're done. It grows with your animation.

That is, don't explicitly set the height of #main-content in your CSS and don't animate the height of #main-content, as it auto-grows with the content within.

If you want to achieve some kind of min-height or padding below your youtube video, then you can use min-height or padding-bottom.